# Installing different Python version in virtualenv with installing version 3.5.1 from source

Tags: pip, opensuse, python-3.5

I'm running openSUSE 13.1 and I'm trying to install Python 3.5.1 in an virtualenv, because the system default is 3.3.5 and cannot be further updated with yast.

I have downloaded the source, stored it in folder `~/pysrc35` and created a new directory `~/localpython` and installed it

`./configure --prefix=/home/<user>/.localpython
make
make install`

the python3 executable there works and the `localpython/bin` looks like 

`2to3      easy_install-3.5  idle3.5  pip3.5  pydoc3.5  python3.5         python3.5m         python3-config  pyvenv-3.5
2to3-3.5  idle3             pip3     pydoc3  python3   python3.5-config  python3.5m-config  pyvenv`

Now I want to use pip, which seems to have been included in the installation, but when I run it I get the error:

`ImportError: No module named 'pip'`

I have already set $PYTHONHOME to `/home/<usr>/localpython/bin/python3` and $PYTHONPATH to `/home/<usr>/localpython/lib/python3.5/:/home/<usr>/localpython/lib64/python3.5/:/home/<usr>/localpython/include/python3.5m/`, because I got errors on that before, but now I'm stuck with pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great solution for this was using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). This tool makes installing different python versions and virtual environments super easy. The only prerequisite is probably just having `git` installed. Then you clone it

> ```
> git clone git://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
> git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
> ```

and run

> ```
> echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
> echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
> echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
> eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
> ```

in terminal. For Linux distributions other than openSUSE or Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` might have to be replaced by 
`~/.bash_profile`

. After restarting the terminal, run

> `pyenv install 3.5.x`

to install whatever version you want (except 3.5.1 is not yet available). Then you should switch to your desired Python version, e.g. with

> `pyenv shell 3.5.x`

to set the version for the current terminal session.

After that a virtual environment can be created and activated by

> ```
> pyenv virtualenv /path/to/venv 
> pyenv activate /path/to/venv
> ```

See also [this video](https://godjango.com/96-django-and-python-3-how-to-setup-pyenv-for-multiple-pythons/) for a comprehensive tutorial on using pyenv and in conjunction with django.